# Dart Transformer fails to overwrite an Asset

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I wrote an AggregateTransformer that is supposed to overwrite the main.dart file with an updated version (change the imports).

```
Asset mainAsset = await _getFileAsset(transform, "main.dart");
Asset updatedMainAsset = await _replaceDefaultImport(mainAsset, transform.package, "default.dart", newLibFileName);

//overwrite mainAsset because mainAsset and updatedMainAsset have the same id
transform.addOutput(updatedMainAsset);
```

(removing the asset first before adding the new version doesn't change anything:)

```
transform.consumePrimary(mainAsset.id);
transform.addOutput(updatedMainAsset);
```

But the updated version vanishes without a trace. Trying to retrieve it by id yields the original content:

```
Asset updatedMainAssetRetrieved = await transform.getInput(updatedMainAsset.id);
```

The transformer outputs the content of mainAsset and updatedMainAsset so you can check that the content of updatedMainAsset is indeed updated. Invoke the transformer by invoking **pub run main.dart**.

The complete code/pseudo-code looks like this:

```
class ReplacePackageTransformer extends AggregateTransformer {
  ReplacePackageTransformer.asPlugin();

  @override
  String classifyPrimary(AssetId id) => id.toString().endsWith(".dart") ? "dart-files" : null;

  @override
  apply(AggregateTransform transform) {
    //capture the whole execution to allow better stacktraces if an error occurs
    Chain.capture(() async {
      //create a file lib/replacement.dart that defines the same method as lib/default.dart
      final newLibFileName = "replacement.dart";
      final newLibAsset = _createReplacementAsset(...);
      //add this new asset
      transform.addOutput(newLibAsset);

      //rewrite main.dart to import replacement.dart instead of default.dart. To that end:
      //1) retrieve the asset for main.dart
      Asset mainAsset = await _getFileAsset(transform, "main.dart");
      //2) create a new asset with the same id as mainAsset but with updated content
      Asset updatedMainAsset = await _replaceDefaultImport(mainAsset, ...);
      //3) adding this asset should overwrite/replace the original main.dart-asset because they use the same id
      transform.addOutput(updatedMainAsset);
    });
  }

  //helper methods ...
}
```

You can find the whole transformer (and the rest of the project) [here](https://github.com/simon-void/code_replacing_transformer/blob/master/lib/transformer.dart).

**Update/Solution**

Dennis Kaselow is right! The apply-method of my transformer has to return a Future (so that subsequent transformers can wait for it to be done)! Adding a *return* before the call to Chain.capture would have been sufficient (because the callback i capture has an async body and returns therefore a Future that capture will forward/return).

So changing

```
apply(AggregateTransform transform) {
  Chain.capture(() async {...});
  //no return statement so void is returned
}
```

to

```
Future apply(AggregateTransform transform) {
  return Chain.capture(() async {...});
  //() async {...} returns a Future that Chain.capture and apply forward/return
}
```

solves my problem!

Comment: This seems related https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/editor/vz-arQ_KEFM. No idea if it helps. I'd suggest you post the link to this SO question to https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc

Comment: Not sure my issue is related with the one you linked, because that one was about a part-file and they proposed inlining. While my asset was a single file-library (without parts), so it was already inlined.
I added a post in dart-misc which is not yet online because the first post is moderated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: just add a `return` in front of your `Chain.capture`.

The dartdoc of `apply` says:

> If this does asynchronous work, it should return a [Future] that completes once it's finished.

If you access the input after transforming, the input will still be the original input. You don't need to call `transform.consumeInput` either.